# Jquery Find iFrame with Highest Z-index and Create Link

Tags: jquery, scope, z-index

I'm trying to go through a bunch of divs (.subtab-content) that have multiple iframes in each, and for each I'm looking for the iframe with the highest z-index to create a link.

```
$('.subtab-content').each(function(){       
  var topZindex = 0;
  var topFrameId;                                                                    
  $('.subtab-content iframe').each(function(){                                                                          
    var currentZindex = parseInt($(this).css('z-index'), 10);
    if(currentZindex > topZindex) {
      topZindex = currentZindex;
      topFrameId = this.id;
    }
  });
  var src = $(topFrameId).attr('src');
  $(this).before('<div><a href="'+src+'" target="_blank">Go</a></div>');
});
```

I think the problem might be with the scope of the variables, but I'm having trouble figuring it out. Here's a fiddle of the basic structure (z-index is increased when a dropdown menu is changed):
https://jsfiddle.net/6ftm1cm1/2/

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you give a **jsFiddle** with html code in it

Comment: Yes, I've added a fiddle.